# What do i have to consider to write a script that reacts on a keypress?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I know i can read within a script something into a variable, like this: 
variable = read
But i have to press enter in order to submit the value into the variable. 
What do i have to know in order to submit the value of a keypress into a variable without hitting enter, or if not submitting into a variable just to react when a certain key is pressed ?

Comment: first ask user to enter the variable value then validate that value accordingly

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`, you can use the `-n` parameter to the built-in `read` function to limit the number of characters read without requiring a newline:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ready? [Y/n]: "
read -n 1 y_or_n
echo

case "$y_or_n" in
    [Yy]|"")
        echo "you said yes"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "you said no"
        ;;
esac
```

This works whether `bash` is invoked as `sh` or `bash`.

See `help read` or the `bash` manpage for more details.

Note that other shells may not support the `-n` parameter to `read`. `dash`, for example, does not.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. `sh` could be linked to `dash` or another shell that doesn't support `read -n`.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about the shell's `read` is - whether you limit its total byte count per `read` or not - it's still not going to get you a *keypress* per `read`. It's only going to get some *fixed* number of *characters* per `read`. In order to get a *keypress* per `read` you need to block out your input - and the best way to do that is probably `dd`. This is a shell function I wrote a couple of months ago when I was experimenting w/ `dd` blocking on terminal i/o:

```
printkeys()(    IFS= n=1
    set -f -- "$(tty <&2)"
    exec    <${1##[!/]*};set \\t
    _dd()(  c=conv=sync,unblock i=ibs=72 b=bs=8
            dd bs=7 ${c%,*} |   dd $i o$b c$b $c
    )       2>/dev/null
    trap "  trap '' TTOU TTIN
            stty '$(stty -g
            stty raw isig inlcr)'   "   INT EXIT
    _dd |while  ${2:+:} read -r c   ||  exit 2
            do  case $#:$c in (1:): ;; 
        (*:?*)  set ":%d$@"         \
                    \'${c%"${c#?}"} ;
                c=${c#?}            ;; 
        (*)     printf "$@"         ;
        [ 0 -eq $((n=n<4?n+1:0)) ]  &&
                set '\n\r'||set \\t ;;  esac
        done
)
```

You see, in the above case, the terminal input is filtered on two `dd` processes  in a pipeline. The terminal is set with `stty` to *raw* mode in a `trap` which also restores the terminal state on `INT`errupt or `EXIT` to whatever it was when the function was called *(which can be done with CTRL+C probably, or whatever your interrupt key is)*. In *raw* mode a terminal flushes input to any reader as soon as it arrives - keypress by keypress. It doesn't just push a byte at a time; it pushes the entire buffer as soon as it possibly can. And so when you press the UP arrow, for example, and your keyboard sends an escape sequence like:

```
^[[A
```

...which is three bytes, and it pushes that all at once.

`dd` is spec'd to satisfy any read as soon as it is offered - no matter how high you set its `ibs=`. This means that, though I set it with `ibs=7`, when the terminal pushes only three bytes a read is still completed. Now that's difficult to handle with most any other utility, but `dd`'s `conv=sync` fills out the difference w/ `\0NUL` bytes. So when you push the UP arrow on your keyboard, `dd` reads three bytes and writes 7 to the next `dd` - the three bytes in the escape sequence and 4 more `\0NUL`s.

But in order to pull that data in with the shell's read you've gotta block it again, so the next `dd` syncs out its input buffer to 72 bytes - but it also `conv=unblock`s it. With the `unblock` conversion, `dd` splits its input on `\n`ewline delimiters for its `cbs=` count - which is here 8. With `sync` and `unblock` *(or `block`)* conversions, `dd` doesn't synchronize on `\0NUL`s, but rather on trailing spaces. So for every 7 bytes the first `dd` writes to the pipe between them, the second `dd` buffers 72 bytes - the first few are whatever the keypress was, then `\0NUL`s, then 65 spaces at the tail of each read.

The other thing `unblock` does is elide trailing spaces - it will eat as many spaces as might occur at the tail-end of each of its `cbs=` conversion blocks. So because `dd` writes output at `obs=8` bytes per write, it writes 9 lines per read in  2 total writes to the output pipe. The first write is the first line and consists of the 7 bytes read from the input pipe and a trailing newline - one more byte. The next write is 8 newlines - all at once and in a row - 8 more bytes - because `dd` eats all 8 spaces for each of those 8 conversion blocks.

On the other side of those two `dd`s a shell `while` loop `read`s line by line. It can ignore blank lines - because the terminal is converting all newlines to carriage returns on output anyway according to the `inlcr` `stty` option. But when it detects even a single byte in `$c` after the shell's input is `read` into its value, then you have a keypress - and a whole one too, so long as your keyboard is not sending more than 7 bytes per keystroke *(though that would just need a different blocking factor)*.

When the shell has a keypress in `$c` it iterates over it byte for byte and splits it out into an array divided by `'` characters, then `printf`s the decimal values for every byte in `$c` all at once. If you run that function, you should get output like this:

```
a:97    b:98    c:99    d:100   e:101
f:102   ;:59    ^M:13   ^M:13   ^M:13
s:115   a:97    d:100   f:102    :32
':39    ':39    ':39    a:97    s:115
d:100   f:102   ;:59    ':39    ^[[A:27:91:65
^[[D:27:91:68   ^[[B:27:91:66   ^[[C:27:91:67   ^[[D:27:91:68   ^[[C:27:91:67
^[[A:27:91:65   ^[[D:27:91:68   ^[[C:27:91:67   ^[[B:27:91:66   ^[[D:27:91:68
^[[C:27:91:67   ^[[A:27:91:65   ^[[D:27:91:68   ^[[C:27:91:67   ^[[B:27:91:66
```

Because the `\0NUL`s that `dd` inserts to block out the keypresses evaporate as soon as the shell fills out a variable's value with its input - you can't put `\0NUL`s in a shell variable *(in any shell but `zsh` - in which case it is still configurable that way)*. As far as I know this should work in any shell - and it definitely does work in `bash`, `dash`, and `ksh93`. It might even reliably handle multibyte input - but I won't swear to it.

In the demo output above, the actual output of the function is preceded for each write by other information which it does not write. Each displayed character preceding each first occurring `:` in any of the above sequences is actually the terminal's `echo` as can be configured w/ `stty echo` or `-echo`. The rest is what is printed as the function's output - and it is printed, as you can see, just as soon as it is typed.